# Solrnet /ASP.NET sample without MVC

Tags: asp.net, lucene, solr, solrnet

I am trying to get a handle on Solrnet and interacting an ASP.NET site with a Solr server. However, the sample app (on the code repository) is MVC based ,does anyone know of a version in plain vanilla ASP.NET?

Thanks

Comment: Interaction between asp.net and Solr would be the same regardless of MVC or WebForms, wouldn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily, AFAIK the webforms querying etc. model is different from MVC.

Comment: @Mikos: Yes, getting parameters from the page and passing them on will be different, but I assume that's not the part of the interaction you're trying to figure out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't any major differences really:

- Initialize the library in your Application_Start() just like in the MVC sample app.
- The simplest way to use it in a code-behind is to use the service locator to get the main SolrNet interface  (e.g. `var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<MyDocumentClass>>()`), (in MVC it's easy to instead inject the interface using an IoC container)
- Then you can use that instance to run any query you want, update documents, etc. In the MVC sample app a ModelBinder is used to get the search parameters from the querystring, but that's a MVC feature, so getting the search parameters is up to you.
- Then bind the query results to the page (I mostly use a simple foreach, you could also try ObjectDataSource)

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: It's not terribly difficult to do dependency injection in webforms as well, you just can't (as far as I know) do constructor dependency injection. http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AspNetIntegration

Comment: @r0manarmy: exactly; if you can't take control of instantiation you can only *hack around it*. Not the real thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is little late. But for people still looking for Solrnet /ASP.NET sample without MVC can look at the following:
http://crazorsharp.blogspot.com/2010/01/full-text-search-using-solr-lucene-and.html
http://blog.dileno.com/archive/201009/get-started-using-solr-for-search-with-aspnet/