# Is there any SolrNet DemoApp or open-source app of C# webform?

Tags: asp.net, solrnet, solr

I had found a SolrNet client Demo Sample App, but it is ASP.NET MVC:

http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/downloads/list

Is there any Solr Client Demo App or open-source app of C# ASP.NET webform?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solrnet /ASP.NET sample without MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660239/solrnet-asp-net-sample-without-mvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mauricio Scheffer for your answer. Now I can use SolrNet in a webform app.